# No IMEI for Android Developers in Android 10

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager, imei, android-10.0

As Android is serious about security and trying to make new android versions more secure, its becoming tough for developers to keep up-to date with new security features and find old methods alternatives to make their app compatible with old features.

**This question is about IMEI in New Android 10!**
The old method was super easy to get IMEI number by using below code

```
  String deviceId = "";

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        if (telMgr.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA) {
            deviceId = telMgr.getMeid();
        } else if (telMgr.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) {
            deviceId = telMgr.getImei();
        } else {
            deviceId = ""; // default!!!
        }
    } else {
        deviceId = telMgr.getDeviceId();
    }
```

In New Android 10 it is now restricted to get IMEI number. According to android documentation

> apps must have the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE privileged permission in order to access the device's non-resettable identifiers, which include both IMEI and serial number.

The problem is that when we try to ask run time permissions with

```
  android.Manifest.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE
```

My compiler does not recognize this permissions and i got error on this line but when i ask this permission in manifest file it does recognize this line but through warning that this permission is only for system apps.

I want to make my app compatible with Android 10 and want to get IMEI. How can i get IMEI number in Android 10 without becoming device owner or profile owner ?

Comment: you cannot access IMEI in android 10 unless you're developing a system-level app. You can use other unique identifiers though: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am getting IMEI null in Android Q?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55173823/i-am-getting-imei-null-in-android-q)

Answer (score 3):

Only device owner apps can read unique identifiers or your app must be a system app with `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE`. You can't ask this permission for a normal app.

Comment: with device owner app can we get IMEI in android 10 ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it

Comment: is there any possibility we can get this permission programmatically without root ?

Comment: No, you can't do it.

Comment: its too hard to root latest patches :/ Plaase any suggestion you want to give me for rooting easily ?

Answer (score 3):

Android 10 Restricted developer to Access IMEI number.

You can have a alternate solution by get Software ID. You can use software id as a unique id. Please find below code as i use in Application.

```
 public static String getDeviceId(Context context) { 

    String deviceId;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

}else {

final TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);



     if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null) {
            deviceId = mTelephony.getDeviceId();
        } else {
            deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(
                    context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        }
    }

return deviceId;

}
```

Comment: Thank you it works and save my day

Comment: this one line enough -> "deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);"
 
You can't get READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission for normal applications

Answer (score 1):

To get a unique identifier you can use `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId();` or `String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();`. Have a look here for best practices https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#java