# How get IMEI of device?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, telephonymanager

I a beginner in android development and I try to get device **IMEI** but I have a problem of permission.

I don't have `android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` property in my project but the function `getImei()` of `TelephonyManger.java` require this permission.

How can I resolve this? I am a little lost.

Comment: In short you can't as android has elevated the permission model regarding device hardware id your has to be the device owner/profile ower to get the permission to get device IMEI. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids

Comment: Yes I could see that, but we don't have a solution to get this new permission ? What does it mean, "be the device owner/profile owner" ?

Comment: @Piyush if you have a solution (i think i'm dreaming xD)

Comment: No, you can't give the permission, The `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` permission is only granted to apps signed with the platform key and privileged system apps. -

Comment: Thanks @Nitish, so we can't get the IMEI... We have to ask the user for this...

Comment: I don't think any user will be willing to share such info. It's better to look for alternative - [Beast practice for unquies ids](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) , [no-imei-for-android-developers-in-android-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57993401/no-imei-for-android-developers-in-android-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is sad. **We can't** !

Like @Nitsh said, *"The `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` permission is only granted to apps signed with the platform key and privileged system apps"*.

Answer (score 0):

try use below code  in kotlin.

```
val telephonyManager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as
     TelephonyManager
     if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@MainActivity,
     Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity,
        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE), REQUEST_CODE)
        return@setOnClickListener
     }  
     IMEINumber = telephonyManager.deviceId
```

this link would be helpful.
[How to get the device's IMEI/ESN programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-get-the-devices-imei-esn-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Thanks, but from what I understand **READ_PHONE_STATE** is no longer the correct permission for this :)