# Get IMEI number for android 10

Tags: android, imei

How to get IMEI number for android 10?? Is there having any alternative way for finding unique id for dual sim slots

I need a unique identifier for dual sim slots id for android10. For android9 and below imei number is capturing based on sim slots. What is the way to capture unique device id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get IMEI information in Andorid 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58180656/how-to-get-imei-information-in-andorid-10)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the unique device id this will help you

```
 private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

but there is a catch ,this will come as String not number.