# Andorid 10 Unique Identification of android device

Tags: android

In android from version 10 or API 29 . How can I get unique identification of device.

or how can I get the IMEI number from android 10

Comment: Read this for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/58180783/7639056

Answer (score 2):

If you just want unique identifier for your app instance, you can use.

```
Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
```

However this not unique device identifier, but for each app + user + device combination: As per the android docs

> ANDROID_ID:  On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher versions of the platform, a
>   64-bit number (expressed as a hexadecimal string), unique to each
>   combination of app-signing key, user, and device.

For more information read this [document from android dev](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure) and [this stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799394/is-secure-android-id-unique-for-each-device)

Comment: I'll try this. On latest version

Comment: Sure, do let me know if it meets your requirement (also kindly mark it as answer if it satisfies your requirement !)

Answer (score 1):

If you are supporting tablets which doesn't support calling functionality or doesn't have sim card slot then IMEI thing won't work for you try Instance Id https://developers.google.com/instance-id

or else if you can use 
Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID) returns a String. 
In Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Followed by generic code for permissions and once you have the required permission just do Build.getSerial();

Answer (score 0):

On Android 10, due to security concerns, third party apps cannot get the IMEI information anymore.
You would need the app to have the android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission, usually given to system applications.

With the permission granted, you can use something like this to get the device id which is more commonly used than IMEI

```
String serial;
    try {
        serial = Build.getSerial();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // missing PHONE permission
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not get hardware serial number", e);
        serial = null;
    }
```