# java.lang.SecurityException onRequestPermissionsResult

Tags: java, android

I have created device info app but my app only crash in android 10. Please tell me how to solve this issue

> java.lang.SecurityException
>   com.marsad.deviceinfo.DeviceIDActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult

Here is the **logcat**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:5096)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult (ActivityThread.java:5137)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute (ActivityResultItem.java:51)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2146)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7770)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1047)
>   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: 
>     at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:2088)
>     at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2056)
>     at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2004)
>     at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getDeviceId (ITelephony.java:11175)
>     at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId (TelephonyManager.java:2282)
>     at com.marsad.deviceinfo.DeviceIDActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult (DeviceIDActivity.java:17)
>     at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult (Activity.java:8500)
>     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult (Activity.java:8322)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:5089)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult (ActivityThread.java:5137)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute (ActivityResultItem.java:51)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2146)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7770)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1047)

**Code :**

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION:{
                if (grantResults.length>=0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    recreate(); //restart activity on permission granted
                    imei = tm.getDeviceId();
                    simSerial = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
                    simSubscriberID = tm.getSubscriberId();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Enable READ_PHONE_STATE Permission From Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }


        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

Comment: You can't read the device IMEI in Android 10. Please see [How do I get information about a phone's IMEI in Android 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58180656/how-do-i-get-information-about-a-phones-imei-in-android-10).