# How to get device id or IMEI programmatically in android Q?

Tags: java, android, android-10.0, deviceid

I am trying to get the imei number of the phone by using telephonymanager in android . but in Android Q , I am not getting the device imei .

Is there any way to imei number in android Q programmatically?

```
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    IMEINumber = tm.getDeviceId();
```

Returning null in Android Q

Comment: This question probably answers your issue. Third party apps can no longer get the IMEI number and other non-resettable device identifiers in Android Q+ [I am getting IMEI null in Android Q?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55173823/i-am-getting-imei-null-in-android-q)