# Android cannot get IMEI on Android Q 10

Tags: android

I have read this post:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids

I tried to use device or profile owner app via EMM deployment but my app still cannot get IMEI, even I declared and request runtime permissions:
            "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE",
            "android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"

Does anyone have solution? Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am getting IMEI null in Android Q?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55173823/i-am-getting-imei-null-in-android-q)

Answer (score 0):

As they mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy#top-privacy-changes), `Restrictions on accessing device serial and IMEI`.
Please check this [article](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids) for more info.

Comment: But they mentioned:
If your app is the device or profile owner app, you need only the READ_PHONE_STATE permission to access non-resettable device identifiers, even if your app targets Android 10 or higher.
I tried this solution but still cannot get IMEI.

Comment: @SyNguyenDinh any solution so far ?

Comment: @Ahmad still not bro :(