# SIM serial information API level 29

Tags: android

Willing to gather SIM serial information (aka ICCID) through SDK. The current method [TelephonyManager#getSimSerialNumber](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getSimSerialNumber()) does not seem to work on API level 29. However, I have seen other Apps working fine on Android 10. Any hint of how this can be alternatively achieved? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you requested the `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` permission? It's required in API level 29 and onward as per [the Privacy changes that came with that release](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes).

[image: Privacy changes Android 10]

Comment: Hi. I tried without success. Seems it has been restricted by Google, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55173823/i-am-getting-imei-null-in-android-q

Comment: Did you try this workaround? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59560877/860212